# Finite and Infinite Field Extensions of Complex

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I have a couple questions regarding field extensions $L/\mathbb{C}$, first I believe that if $L/\mathbb{C}$ is a finite extension $([L:\mathbb{C}]) = n$ then this will imply that $L = \mathbb{C}$, i.e., there are no finite degree extensions of the complex numbers which 'enlarge' the complex numbers.  Here is my attempt at this statement: If $L$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ then for a basis $\{l_1, l_2, ..., l_n\} \subset L$, an arbitrary element $x$ in $L$ must be of the form

$$
x = c_1l_1 + c_2l_2 + ... + c_nl_n
$$

for a suitable choice of complex scalars $c_1, c_2, ..., c_n$.  I believe the remaining portion of this proof follows somehow from the fact that $\mathbb{C}$ is an algebraically closed field, but I'm unsure of how to proceed.  $\mathbb{C}$ being algebraically closed implies that for any nonzero polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x]$, all of the roots of $f$ are contained within $\mathbb{C}$.  Unfortunately, I can't use this fact from the above representation of an arbitrary element in $L$ since I would need to use some polynomial in $n$ indeterminates ($f(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x_1, x_2, ..., x_n]$), and I'm not sure if algebraic closure implies anything about polynomial roots in $n$ indeterminates.  Also, I'm unsure of how I would even apply this if it were true - to get a root, I would need to set $x = 0$ but then that wouldn't really be proving anything.

Secondly, I believe that there are extensions of $\mathbb{C}$ which are uncountable.  Namely the field of rational functions in $n$ indeterminates with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$.  Would such an uncountable degree extensions be referred to as a transcendental extension?  And if the degree of the extension were instead countable, would this say anything about the field extension $L$?

Comment: For the first part, it is a standard fact that [a finite dimensional extension of a field $F$ is algebraic over $F$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_extension).

Comment: Can this be extended to a countable degree extension then?  If it is true for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ that $[L:\mathbb{C}] = n$ implies that $L$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{C}$, then in a sense could we 'look at the limit' as $n \rightarrow \infty$?  If at every step the extension is trivial, repeating this argument countably many times would give the result?

Comment: $\mathbb{C}$ does not have a proper extension of countable degree. Since $\mathbb{C}(X)$ has uncountable dimension over $\mathbb{C}$, such an extension would be algebraic,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Q1:** Yes, this is true. More generally we have the following standard fact.

> **Proposition:** Any finite extension $L/K$ of fields is algebraic.

*Proof.* Let $\alpha \in L$ be any element. If $\dim_K L = [L : K] = n$ then $\{ 1, \alpha , \alpha^2, \dots \alpha^n \}$ consists of $n+1$ vectors and so must be linearly dependent. A linear dependence between these gives a polynomial $f$ of degree at most $n$ such that $f(\alpha) = 0$, so $\alpha$ is algebraic. $\Box$

> **Corollary:** If $K$ is algebraically closed and $L/K$ is a finite extension, then $L = K$.

**Q2:** Uncountability is not the definition of a transcendental extension; an extension is transcendental if it is not algebraic, or equivalently if it has at least one transcendental element. Over $\mathbb{C}$ these two conditions are equivalent, but over a countable or finite field they are not; for example $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ is a countable transcendental extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.

**Q3:** $\mathbb{C}$ has no countable extensions. This is because a transcendental extension must contain $\mathbb{C}(x)$ as a subfield, and $\mathbb{C}(x)$ has uncountable dimension over $\mathbb{C}$ because, for example, the elements $\frac{1}{x - a}, a \in \mathbb{C}$ are linearly independent. (This is a nice exercise.)

This is specifically because $\mathbb{C}$ is itself uncountable. More generally, for $K$ a field, $K(x)$ is countable-dimensional over $K$ if $K$ is finite or countable, and otherwise its dimension is the cardinality of $K$. (This is also a nice exercise. You can do it by proving partial fraction decomposition.)